# How to understand the prvalue within list-initialization of a reference

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(int) {

    }
};
int main() {
    A const& rf = { 0 };
}
```

Cite the quote in standard here:

> Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a **prvalue(#1)** of the type referenced by T is generated. The **prvalue** initializes its result object by **copy-list-initialization or direct-list-initialization**, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference. The **prvalue** is then used to direct-initialize the reference. [ Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type.  — end note ]

I don't understand the "prvalue" at `#1`,How to denote this prvalue? And continue, why use the prvalue initialize its reuslt object by `list-initialization` again,and why not use the reuslt object to direct-initialize the reference instead using the prvalue?

To descript the prvalue concretely,Does `A{0}` denote the prvalue(at #1)?

#### So my questions are:

1.How to denote the prvalue (at #1) or what actullay the `prvalue` is

2.Since a prvalue of type T'(remove reference) has been generated,why not use the prvalue direct-initialize the reference

3.I very confused about "The prvalue initializes its result object" by **list-initialization** again

Comment: "*How to denote the prvalue*" What do you mean by "denote" in this context? It's a prvalue; that's the beginning and the end of it.

Comment: @NicolBolas my meaning is that what actually the prvalue(#1) is,Or in other words,How to use code to denote the "pure value" of type T'

Comment: Again, I don't understand the question. What it is is a prvalue of the type referenced by `T`. The specific characteristics of the prvalue are explained in the following sentences. What other characteristics are you expecting to find?

Comment: @NicolBolasN Could you left an answers about how to understand the quote I mentioned above,may be I have some misunderstanding about "prvalue",if you could ,interpret how to understand the prvalue together

Comment: @NicolBolas such as interger literal "0" is the prvalue,class type T ，T() is the prvalue,so  what is the prvalue in "A const& rf = { 0 };"?

Comment: `T()` is not a prvalue; it is a piece of C++ grammar. The rules of C++ says that such an expression results in a prvalue. It's the rules of C++ that define where prvalues happen. This is just one more rule in which a prvalue appears. Think of it like implicit conversion, where an object gets created by something that isn't directly visible in the code. You can't point to a single piece of grammar that says "convert X to Y", but the rules of C++ still say that it happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209969/discussion-between-jack-x-and-nicol-bolas).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what actullay the prvalue is

A prvalue is a kind of expression. In C++17 and beyond, it is specifically a kind of expression that initializes an object. So a prvalue is just a mechanism for initializing an object. As such, the only characteristics of a prvalue are the type of the prvalue (ie: the type of the object it will initialize) and the mechanism that it will use to initialize that object.

How the prvalue gets used determines which object gets initialized by it.

So, what is the prvalue in this instance? It's an initializer that uses a form of list-initialization on some object of the type referenced by `T`. That is all there is to know about the prvalue.

> why not use the prvalue direct-initialize the reference

The prvalue *does* "direct-initialize" the reference. The spec you quoted says so: "The prvalue is then used to direct-initialize the reference."

If what you're asking is why there is a prvalue between the braced-init-list (aka: `{...}`) and the reference, it's because, on some level, the code you have written makes no sense.

A reference refers to an object, and thus must be initialized by giving it an object. A braced-init-list is not an object; in fact, it isn't even an *expression*. It is a grammatical construct used to initialize an object. So you tried to initialize a reference to an object with something that isn't an object. By all rights, this should be a compile error.

However, there is an obvious interpretation as to what your code *meant* to do. Namely, use the braced-init-list to initialize an object, then use the object to initialize the reference. So that's what C++ does.

> I very confused about "The prvalue initializes its result object" by list-initialization again

As previously stated, a prvalue consists of two things: the type of an object to be initialized by the prvalue, and the mechanism to use to initialize it. This sentence explains the latter part.

Comment: "The prvalue initializes its result object by copy-list-initialization or direct-list-initialization",so this sentence interpret how the prvalue initialize an object by using the specified way(Namely,copy-list-initialization or direct-list-initialization),Do you agree?

Comment: Since the prvalue is used to initialize an object,why not use the reult object to direct-initialize the reference ,instead in the quote it use prvalue,how to interpret this?

Comment: @jackX: "*why not use the reult object to direct-initialize the reference*" It is. Look up what it means to direct initialize a reference from a prvalue.